# Primefaces Watermark Password is not working

Tags: jsf

I have password field in jsf page. I want to display watermark text "Enter password" in password field but it is not displaying text. The code is

```
<p:password id="password" value="#{passwordBean.password1}" required="true" />  
    <p:watermark for="password" value="Enter password" />
```

How we can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are using an older version of primefaces , it was fixed in pf 3.0

here is the issue ticket : [Issue 2924: Password Field with Watermark do not work](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2924)

Upgrade your primefaces version jar